# How to add transitions in react

Tags: reactjs

Iam new to reactjs.I want to add animations in react using transitions.I am including as

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.ReactCSSTransitionGroup;
```

But Iam getting error as

```
try.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCSSTransitionGroup' of undefined(…)(anonymous function) @ try.js:1n.run @ browser.min.js:3l @ browser.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ browser.min.js:3s.onreadystatechange @ browser.min.js:3
```

Can anyone tell me the solution how to include transitions in react

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install npm i react-addons-css-transition-group`

And then something like this -

`var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');`

Does that work for you?

Comment: @VijayKumarB Are you using CDN library of react? Or are you using `npm`?